# How to call the process of filling missing data after a database upgrade?

Tags: database, terminology

My webapp is periodically collecting data samples (say of type A and B) from some web services. Its database has therefore columns for A and B. So we have values A1/B1, A2/B2 etc.

Requirements have changed and now we want to also collect C. More code and more DB columns are added, so now we collect A3/B3/C3 etc. . But we also want to retroactively collect the missing data, i.e. C1 and C2.

Is there an established term for this process of retroactively filling data in order to make a DB complete again? I initially called it "migration" but my fellow developers use it for DB migrations, i.e. adding/removing columns. I'm looking for a term that is more specific than "data upgrade".

Comment: I've also used the term **back-filling** to describe this process.

Comment: There is no "standard term" for each and every special activity in software development. Just use a description your team understands, like "default initialization of the newly introduced columns".

Comment: “Retroactively filling in data” seems like a perfectly good term.

Answer (score 2):

Migration is perfectly fitting.

From the application's perspective, the data that comes from the database yesterday had different expectations in the yesterday's code revision.

Today, a new code revision gets deployed, and the new code expects the data to have a different format, or in your case, have data points for a specific type of data. That was not the case yesterday. So the data needs to be `migrated` to the new format, but migrating, in your case, means to fill data for entries that haven't existed.

A migration is the perfect use case for this: Ideally, your migration infrastructure lets the migration happen in a transaction so that as soon as the transaction is committed, all the data is there and in the new format.

The migration process could even require you to query some kind of remote web API to get the old values for the missing rows. That's perfectly fine, nobody said a migration has to be quick. Migrations can take days, or weeks.